# Nginx API Gateway is blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: nginx

When we use Nginx(or Nginx Pluz) as an API Gateway for high throughput and concurrent requests, are the http calls made in a blocking or non-blocking manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx uses non-blocking architecture - [nginx architecture](https://www.nginx.com/resources/library/infographic-inside-nginx/).

Most of the industry standard reverse-proxy servers are non-blocking, including Apache HTTPD server.